# Can i run the latest version of Ubuntu on this computer?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 20.04, graphics

Hello I am moving from Windows to Ubuntu the problem is that my computer is weak. I have already tested the latest version of Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) and it sucks to do the most basic things like surfing the internet and using Libre Office, I also tested Ubuntu flavors and what worked best was Ubuntu Mate I think the problem of slowness has to do with the integrated graphics card which is an intel g33 / g31 express chipset family and I also have a lot of screen tearing in moving windows, watching videos and sometimes the computer freezes, I don't know what to do, I really like Ubuntu and I wanted use it smooth, i'm currently using a natiga version of Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) and it works perfectly but there are many things that the old version doesn't have that i want, the pc settings are down, thanks.

Configs:
Memory: 4Gb 800 MHz DDR2

CPU: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GHz × 2

Graphics: Intel® G33

Architecture: x64

HDD: 320Gb

If you need more information aks me.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 20.04 is a really good choice for an old machine.

Comment: Or Xubuntu 20.04; If you use the compositor, there is no screen tearing.

Comment: There are many lightweight alternatives but, at the end of the day your CPU is getting a bit old. You can use a browser with a handful of tabs open and LibreOffice will open and run. It'll be slow, but you can do it. That's not the only area of your hardware that's going to be a bottleneck and the next two are easy to change. If you add more RAM (start at 8 GB) and an SSD, then you'll notice a huge improvement in your user experience.

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu 20.04 is a bit unstable. Try to use ubuntu 18.04. If your computer is so weak you can try to run Lubuntu or Kubutu. They are more speed than Ubuntu gnome.

Anyway, give us the output of `dmesg -l err` in ubuntu 20.04.